# Issue Resuming UIVIew Animation: ios7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uiimageview

I am animating a UIImageView up and down when the view loads by calling the method animateSettings which does the following:

```
- (void)animateSettings {

    NSLog(@"Animate Settings");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState)
                 animations:^{
                     self.waterImageView.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2-75);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
}
```

The problem is that when I exit the app and return, the animation freezes. I understand why that is, but I can't seem to figure out how to resume it.

I've set `NSNotifications` in the viewDidLoad method to notify me when the view becomes active or it enters the background. Doing the following I call the `animateSettings` method or `removeAnimation` method.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(animateSettings)
                                            name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                          object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(removeAnimation)
                                            name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification
                                          object:nil];
```

Here's my removeAnimation method

```
- (void)removeAnimation {
    NSLog(@"Remove Animation");
    [self.waterImageView.layer removeAllAnimations];
}
```

Problem: Even though the method are being called correctly (NSLogging works) the animation is still frozen.

Comment: You don't need to call `removeAllAnimations` when you go into the background. It is called for you by the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first time you start animating (let's call it **1**) animation code says:

```
self.waterImageView.center = 
    CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2-75);
```

Now let's say you go into the background and return. Your animation code is called again (let's call this **2**):

```
self.waterImageView.center = 
    CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2-75);
```

Okay, but *where is `self.waterImageView` right now*, during **2**? It is already *at* `CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2-75)` - because that is where you put it during **1**!

Therefore nothing happens, because there is no animation if there is no *change* in the value of the animatable property.

Knowing this, the solution is obvious. When you go into the background, or if the animation is stopped for any reason, *put the view back where it was to start with*. Now when you start the animation again, the view has somewhere to animate to.

Comment: Thanks Matt. However, keep in mind that I'm auto-reversing the animation and looping it constantly. I'm also using UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState as an option, however it isn't resuming the animation in flight. Maybe I'm wrong, but if it indeed is how you say it is, it should automatically auto-reverse, correct?

Comment: The position you assign in the animation is the position the view really assumes; the animation is just something that the presentation layer is doing. And resuming in flight can't work because there is no in-flight animation to resume - you removed it! (And in any case the system will remove it.)

Comment: See also the discussion of this kind of animation in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#SECblockbasedviewanimation

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was confused about the presentation and actual change in position. I did exactly what you recommended and went ahead and in the removeAnimation method I set the view back to it's original position. Appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

There are two type error animation that stops..

1-)When new vc opened,  pop up back that it stops..

**Solution :** call animation on viewDidAppear that will solve this
problem

2-) When application go background... and after that going foreground
animations are not work

**Here is my solution it work well with ios14:**

**1-) Implement Protocol**

```
protocol ProtocolStartAnimation {
    func startAnimationAfterBackground()
}
```

**2-) Implement below code in AppDelegate:**

```
  @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


        var window: UIWindow?
    
        var genelDelegate : ProtocolStartAnimation?
  
        func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
     
        genelDelegate?.startAnimationAfterBackground()
    }

}
```

**3-) Implement delegate protocol on ViewController**

```
class MainRootVC: UIViewController,
                  ProtocolStartAnimation  {

    func startAnimationAfterBackground() {
        startAnimation()
    }

}



override func viewDidLoad() {
            
   let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
   appDelegate.genelDelegate = self
            
  }
```